# Could not start springboot-admin:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/ZuulServerAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-batch-admin

when i try to start springboot-admin,it throw : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/ZuulServerAutoConfiguration
Is it my version conflict?

SpringBoot version:2.1.9.RELEASE

SpringCloud version:Greenwich.SR3

SpringBootAdmin version:2.1.5

my main class code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAdminServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class SpringbootAdminApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootAdminApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

my maven code：

```java
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<!-- It's partly dependent-->
<dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.SR3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
```

my configure file :

```java
spring:
  application:
    name: spring-boot-admin
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8010/eureka
server:
  port: 8083
```

I want to start the application

Comment: did u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268604/could-not-start-springboot-admin-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springfram

Comment: I already try do it,but it also failed........

Comment: why do you have spring-cloud dependencies? Even if you need, it should be under dependencyManagement tag.

Comment: oh, it be under dependencyManagement, I already resolve it...just change version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your spring-cloud dependencies under dependencyManagement tag, and try,

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.SR3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Thanks,it be under the dependencyManagement tag, i resolve it,just change springboot version to 1.5.5.RELEASE and cloud version to Edgware.SR5.